# Law of large numbers for non-independent and non-identically distributed samples

Tags: expected-value, sampling, law-of-large-numbers

Let $X \sim p_X$ be a real-valued random variable with $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mu > c$ where $c \in \mathbb{R}.$

Assume you sample from $p_X$ and only accept samples such that the current sample mean is greater than $c$.

Formally,
$$p_{Y_1}(y_1) = \frac{p_X(y_1)\mathbb{I}_{[y_1 > c]}}{\int p_X(y_1)\mathbb{I}_{[y_1 > c]}dy_1}, \dots$$
$$p_{Y_n\vert Y_{1:n-1}}(y_n\vert y_{1:n-1}) = \frac{p_X(y_n)\mathbb{I}_{[\overline{y}_{1:n} > c]}}{\int p_X(y_n)\mathbb{I}_{[\overline{y}_{1:n} > c]}dy_n},$$

where $\overline{y}_{1:n} = \frac{\sum^n_{i=1}y_i}{n}.$

Does it hold that $\overline{y}_{1:n} \overset{p}{\rightarrow} \mu$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: Where did the other comment with the counterexample go?

Comment: O wait, I see now what was wrong with it

Comment: Sorry, it was wrong. I misread the problem! I should finish my coffee first.

Comment: Intuitively I would say the answer must be yes: as time goes on, less and less values need to be excluded and hence the sample looks more and more like a sample from $X$ itself rather than this weird construction.